# Two identical foreign keys on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have these tables:

`Companies (CompanyID, Name, CompanyTypeID)`
`CompanyTypes (CompanyTypeID, Name)`

I want to avoid tables like "TypeACompanies", "TypeBCompanies", etc. But the issue is that there is a many-to-many relationship between two particular company types - one "Retailer" company can have many "Supplier" companies, and one "Supplier" company can supply many "Retailer" companies.

This led to a new linking table with a composite primary key - both fields being foreign keys to `Companies`:

`RetailerCompanies_SupplierCompanies (RetailerCompanyID, SupplierCompanyID)`

Sample data of the linking table:
**(1, 1)

(1, 2)

(1, 3)

(2, 1)

(2, 2)

(2, 3)**

In Entity Framework the `Company` entity look like this (I'm doing Database First):

```
public Company()
{
    this.Companies1 = new HashSet<Company>();
    this.Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
}
```

Is this bad practice? Is there a better way to achieve this relationship?

Comment: Why are you specifically doing Database First? You can model and existing database using Code First. I say this because Database First is a pain in the ass. [watch this](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/5688-orms-you-re-doing-it-wrong)

Comment: Dunno how that's relevant to this question. Some people prefer db first, I'm one of those people

Comment: Fair enough, but definitely watch the video.

Comment: You could always rename those navigation properties to be more appropriate (e.g. RetailCompanies and SupplierCompanies.  They're still collections of Company, but it may be more straightforward.

Comment: @QuietSeditionist you need to be careful in doing that.  Regenerating or updating the model via Database First will recreate the files, and you loose changes.

Comment: @BrendanGreen, you are correct, I should clarify.  You shouldn't edit the model directly, these changes will be lost when model is regenerated.  Instead, you could edit the *.Context.tt file.